# Qt Installer Framework - Windows - Large Font - text not completely visible (License Page)

Tags: qt, installation, font-size

When building an installer for an application, the resulting executable works fine when Windows is using 'normal' fontsize.
When the Windows fontsize is increased, I notice that on the Licence page, the subtitle is not shown completely.
This is the part that says

> License Agreement
>   Please read the following license agreement. You
>   must accept the terms contained in this agreement before continuing
>   with the installation

When using large fonts in Windows, the only visible part is:

> License Agreement
>   Please read the following license agreement.

What I am looking for is a way to change the fontsize of this subtitle.
Is there a way to detect this situation (Windows large fonts)?
I have been trying to add code to the controller js script like this:

```
Controller.prototype.LicenseAgreementPageCallback = function()
{
    var widget = gui.currentPageWidget();
    if (widget != null) {
        //widget.AcceptLicenseRadioButton.checked = true;
        widget.subTitle.setText("this is a subtitle");
    }
}
```

But as the original text always stays the same, I am clearly doing this the wrong way. Any hints? (I have been looking at the docs (http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-customizing-installers.html) to no avail...

Any tips on how to handle this?

Comment: of course I do not expect to change the fontsize by changing the text; I'm just trying to get to the correct widget. The commented code works so 'widget' is the actual License page. Once I have the widget, I may be able to set the fontsize.

Comment: one step further now: this code works, but the size setting does not fix the problem when Windows has big fonts:
`widget.subTitle = "<font color='white' size=3>Please read the following license agreement. You must accept the terms contained in this agreement before continuing with the installation</font>";`

Comment: The only way to correctly do this would be by detecting if Windows is using large fonts...I have no clue how to properly do this in QML/JS